# Getting <generator object <genexpr>

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension

I have 2 lists:

```
first_lst = [('-2.50', 0.49, 0.52), ('-2.00', 0.52, 0.50)]
second_lst = [('-2.50', '1.91', '2.03'), ('-2.00', '1.83', '2.08')]
```

I want to do the following math to it:

Multiply `0.49` by `1.91` (the corresponding values from `first_lst` and `second_lst`), and multiply `0.52` by `2.03` (corresponding values also). I want to do that under condition that values at position `0` in each corresponding tuple is idential so `-2.50` == `-2.50` etc. Obviously, we do the same math for remaning tuples as well.

My code:

```
[((fir[0], float(fir[1])*float(sec[1]), float(fir[2])*float(sec[2])) for fir in first_lst) for sec in second_lst if fir[0] == sec[0]]
```

Generates however some object:

```
[<generator object <genexpr> at 0x0223E2B0>]
```

Can you help me fix the code?

Comment: Your tuples have mismatching types of `string` and `float`. Is that intentional or just an error? Your LC would fail if you have these as your tuples. Since `float` cannot be multiplied to a `string`. See my answer to fix that error.

Comment: I had written this code before I realized I needed to convert everything to float. Will edit it now not to confuse  anyone. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Well Ashwini's answer solves the problem. Generally when you are using list comprehensions, you have to typecast/store the final result into either a list or a tuple.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to use `tuple()` or `list()` to convert that generator expression to a `list` or `tuple`:

```
[tuple((fir[0], fir[1]*sec[1], fir[2]*sec[2]) for fir in first_lst)\
                               for sec in second_lst if fir[0] == sec[0]]
```

Working version of your code:

```
>>> first_lst = [tuple(float(y) for y in x) for x in first_lst]
>>> second_lst = [tuple(float(y) for y in x) for x in second_lst]

>>> [((fir[0],) + tuple(x*y for x, y in zip(fir[1:], sec[1:]))) \
                  for fir in first_lst for sec in second_lst if fir[0]==sec[0]]
[(-2.5, 0.9359, 1.0555999999999999), (-2.0, 0.9516000000000001, 1.04)]
```

Comment: Strangely though, this code gives a `fir is not defined.` error. Is that a problem on my side?

Comment: @SukritKalra the names used in this LC are different from what OP posted.

Comment: His comprehension gives the same error instead of creating a generator object.

Comment: @SukritKalra You must be using `first_lst`  and `second_lst` as the variables names for your tuples.

Comment: Yes, I am. I don't get why that fails the LC. Also, OP has half of his tuple in `float` and half in `string`, so, the LC would fail, you could convert the `string` to `float` explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

Considering that your `first_lst` and `second_lst` are defined as follows.

```
>>> first_lst = [('-2.50', '0.49', '0.52'), ('-2.00', '0.52', '0.50')]
>>> second_lst = [('-2.50', '1.91', '2.03'), ('-2.00', '1.83', '2.08')]
```

The following list comprehension may be useful.

```
>>> [tuple((float(elem[0][0]), float(elem[0][1])*float(elem[1][1]), float(elem[0][2])*float(elem[1][2]))) for elem in zip(first_lst, second_lst) if elem[0][0]==elem[1][0]]
[(-2.5, 0.9359, 1.0555999999999999), (-2.0, 0.9516000000000001, 1.04)]
```

Comment: btw. why if I wanted to add `else` statement at the end would raise an error `invalid syntax`. like this: `if elem[0][0]==elem[1][0] else pass]` It's not at odds with python docs I checked it up now.

Comment: `zip` will only work for elements on the same index, and If I am not wrong then OP is trying to multiply any two tuple whole first elements are same.

Comment: He says each corresponding tuple, so I thought he wanted to work on those with same index.

Comment: To answer OP's question, you can do that just put the `for` statement in the end. Like so. `[tuple((float(elem[0][0]), float(elem[0][1])*float(elem[1][1]), float(elem[0][2])*float(elem[1][2]))) if elem[0][0]==elem[1][0] else '' for elem in zip(first_lst, second_lst)]` For some reason `pass` and `continue` don't work, but you won't need them anyways, if you're trying to skip, the LC will do it anyway.

Answer (score 2):

i had the same problem and found a simpler answer for your question.
only thing you need to do is using original for loop syntax and it works nicely!

this is working version of your code:

```
ans=[]
for fir in first_lst:
    for sec in second_lst:
        if float(fir[0])==float(sec[0]):
             ans.append([fir[0],float(fir[1])*float(sec[1]),float(fir[2])*float(sec[2])])
```

print(ans)

```
output=[['-2.50', 0.9359, 1.0555999999999999], ['-2.00', 0.9516000000000001, 1.04]]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues to look at.

The original code will generate the error:

```
>>> first_lst = [('-2.50', 0.49, 0.52), ('-2.00', 0.52, 0.50)]
>>> second_lst = [('-2.50', '1.91', '2.03'), ('-2.00', '1.83', '2.08')]
>>> [((fir[0], float(fir[1])*float(sec[1]), float(fir[2])*float(sec[2])) for fir in first_lst) for sec in second_lst if fir[0] == sec[0]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <listcomp>
NameError: name 'fir' is not defined
>>>
```

and `<generator object <genexpr>` message is mentioned.

1) Let's fix the the code with minimum amount of changes by creating [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=list%20comprehension#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> first_lst = [('-2.50', 0.49, 0.52), ('-2.00', 0.52, 0.50)]
>>> second_lst = [('-2.50', '1.91', '2.03'), ('-2.00', '1.83', '2.08')]
>>> [(fir[0],fir[1]*float(sec[1]),fir[2]*float(sec[2])) for fir in first_lst for sec in second_lst if fir[0] == sec[0]] # list comprehension
[('-2.50', 0.9359, 1.0555999999999999), ('-2.00', 0.9516000000000001, 1.04)]
>>>
```

2) In the original code, the bracket after `first_lst` `)` is misplaced. 
If we place that bracket after the `sec[0]` instead of list comprehension we get [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html?highlight=generator%20expression#generator-expressions-and-list-comprehensions). And that will cause the `<generator object <genexpr>` message:

```
>>> [((fir[0],fir[1]*float(sec[1]),fir[2]*float(sec[2])) for fir in first_lst for sec in second_lst if fir[0] == sec[0])]  # generator object
[<generator object <genexpr> at 0x00000184EEDE29E8>]
```

In terms of syntax, the only difference is that one uses parenthesis instead of square brackets.

Note: If needed, there are two ways to convert a generator object to the list:

2a) Use asterisk (*) operator to unpack object to the list

```
>>> [*((fir[0],fir[1]*float(sec[1]),fir[2]*float(sec[2])) for fir in first_lst for sec in second_lst if fir[0] == sec[0])]
[('-2.50', 0.9359, 1.0555999999999999), ('-2.00', 0.9516000000000001, 1.04)]
>>>
```

2b) Use explicitly `list()`

```
>>> list((fir[0],fir[1]*float(sec[1]),fir[2]*float(sec[2])) for fir in first_lst for sec in second_lst if fir[0] == sec[0])
[('-2.50', 0.9359, 1.0555999999999999), ('-2.00', 0.9516000000000001, 1.04)]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of tuple or list, you are making the generators

```
first_lst = [('-2.50', 0.49, 0.52), ('-2.00', 0.52, 0.50)]
second_lst = [('-2.50', '1.91', '2.03'), ('-2.00', '1.83', '2.08')]
[(fir[0],fir[1]*float(sec[1]),fir[2]*float(sec[2])) for fir in first_lst for sec in 
second_lst if fir[0] == sec[0]] 
output:-[('-2.50', 0.9359, 1.0555999999999999), ('-2.00', 0.9516000000000001, 1.04)]
```