# Change in Type of Brackets changes type of return

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm some code in my project but I came across one problem which I solved but I'm not getting how it works. When I change the type of Brackets used in code,value in year is different.

when I use square brackets in line 2 at start and end of statement after `=`

```
import datetime
years=[x for x in range(2015,datetime.datetime.now().year)]
```

when I `print(years)` it gives output `[2015,2016,2017,2018]`

but when I use round brackets in line 2 like this

`years=(x for x in range(1940,datetime.datetime.now().year))`

when I print it ,it gives output `<generator object <genexpr> at 0x041DB630>`

I don't understand why this happens ,can anyone please explain. Thanks

Comment: That is just the syntax of a list comprehension vs. the syntax of a generator expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generators are functions that can be paused and resumed on the fly, returning an object that can be iterated over. Unlike lists, they are lazy and thus produce items one at a time and only when asked. So they are much more memory efficient when dealing with large datasets.
Just like list comprehensions, generators can also be written in the same manner except they return a generator object rather than a list:

```
>>> my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> gen_obj = (x for x in my_list)
>>> for val in gen_obj:
...     print(val)
...
a
b
c
d
```

Answer (score 2):

These are two different, though related, constructs.

```
[x for x in range(2015,datetime.datetime.now().year)]
```

is known as a *list comprehension*, whereas

```
(x for x in range(2015,datetime.datetime.now().year))
```

is known as a *generator expression*.

Read more at https://djangostars.com/blog/list-comprehensions-and-generator-expressions/

Answer (score 1):

Here are the explanations:

- With round brackets it's called a generator expression, where you would have to do `list(..)` to make it a list and `tuple(..)` to make it a tuple and so on... more on the [documentation](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/generator/)

  > Generator iterators are created by the yield keyword. The real difference between them and ordinary functions is that yield unlike return is both exit and entry point for the function’s body. That means, after each yield call not only the generator returns something but also remembers its state. Calling the next() method brings control back to the generator starting after the last executed yield statement. Each yield statement is executed only once, in the order it appears in the code. After all the yield statements have been executed iteration ends.
- With square brackets it's called a list comprehension, where it would give a list, since square brackets are for lists, more on the [documentation](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/comprehensions/list_comprehension.html)

  > A list comprehension follows the form of the mathematical set-builder notation (set comprehension) as distinct from the use of map() and filter() functions.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a generator expression in the 2nd instance.

You would need to wrap it in `list()` or `tuple()` to get an iterable output.

While in the 1st instance your generating a list.

You can readmore about the issue [Getting <generator object <genexpr>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16373484/getting-generator-object-genexpr)

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying is comprehension and it works by looping or iterating over items and assigning them into a container.

Below is the list comprehension using square brackets:

```
[thing for thing in things]
```

But what you have tried is using parentheses which is generator comprehension **not** tuple comprehension, as parentheses have been kept reserved for generator comprehension, hence:

```
(thing for thing in things)
```

will result in a generator iterator, not a tuple. To get tuple iterator use as done below:

```
tuple(thing for thing in things)
```